# SIFR Newbie: font display problem in non-flash browsers

Tags: css, sifr

I'm wondering if someone can help me with this as I'm fairly new to siFR and think there is something essential i'm not comprehending in the documentation.

I'm having success using siFR 3 (r436) to render fonts and it's working just how I want. However if I turn flash off in any browser the original (no longer rendered) html text displays very badly indeed. 
I thought that in any non-flash browser my *inital* stylesheet would be referred to and not siFR.css and I would be able to adjust the html text as a seperate entity. 
I think i probably developed this bad idea because I remember in earlier siFR versions you had to mess around alot with stylings on the original stylesheet + the sifr-config so you would get corresponding line heights/widths etc between the html and rendered font. (i realise that siFR 3 renders the flash in a different way)

So it seems that siFR.css controls both the non-flash text and the rendered font.

Anyway my essential noob questions is: how do i get the the original html text to have the same dimensions as the rendered font?

thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

sIFR scales up the flash object to match the original font size. The limitation is that your flash text size has to be bigger than the original text.  Use a flash font that matches the metrics of your browser font as closely as possible.

In the CSS, you need to know about the `.sIFR-active`. When you use:

```
sIFR.replace(cochin, {
  selector: 'h1'
});
```

All the `<h1>` elements will be replaced with flash text and the `.sIFR-active` class is added. The purpose is to control how elements are styled when sIFR is active. Particularly, when sIFR is active `visibility` is set to `hidden`.

When flash is off, sIFR is not enabled but according to what you described, you seemed to have written css rules that only match elements with the `sIFR-active` class.

See [sIFR wiki](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/), [How to Use](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use) and [Styling](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Styling) parts.

Comment: thanks for the answer Gregory. Yes I've read the Styling part through on siFR wiki but i think i'm still missing the point.
 
My problem is that when i adjust the font size, letter spacing etc in siFR.css it effects both the rendered font and the original text... should the font-size of the rendered font be derived from siFR-config.js or siFR.css? If from the siFR.css how can i specify to make only the flash size bigger?

Comment: As far as metrics matching: I picked the font to be rendered for cosmetic reasons (it's a thin sans-serif font) and I can't seem to find anything in the common font-families to match it. I guess that's half the problem? 

thanks for your time and any more tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See my edited answer; and I wouldn't use `font-size` Javascript settings. You could go the other way around: style your page without sIFR then use `sIFR-active` class to hide texts replaced by flash and then fine tune sIFR settings

Comment: ok thanks again for the answer. I think that might be the info I was looking for and will check it out today.
cheers

Comment: np, I mean I used sIFR3 last year and then decided to drop it but I remember following the example went smooth. The only part I found tricky was to embed my own font in a .swf. Apart from that, it worked well. So start from something simpler in order to familiarize with the different settings :) good luck!